# Transformation Orientation not working

Tags: axis

I lost hours trying to make the Transformation Orientation function work, but no way. I tried all different axis, but the gizmo doesn't change the orientation. Why does it not work? I changed to 3.5 since 2 weeks ago. It worked on 2.79 before. Perhaps I miss a step on the new version?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe set the top left orientation to Default: https://zupimages.net/up/23/18/gz1e.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual Transformation Orientation settings are for transformation operators(<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>), but the gizmo is a 'tool' so it has separate options in tool settings:

[image]

Or in the Properties Editor, Active Tool and Workspace tab:

[image]

You don't seem to have Tool Settings bar enabled in your viewport. You can right-click the header and choose to enable it:

[image]